# sonarqube v5.4 analysis failed on WARN messages

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-5.4

My cobertura coverage on sonarqube v4.5.6 with runner-2.4, and 2.5.1 has some warning "WARN-File not found:" but the sonar analysis complete successfully.
However, when the same job run on sonarqube v5.4 with same runner versions, the sonar analysis failed with "execution failure". I haven't found a way to ignore this warning for now. Has anyone run into the same issue and got it resolved? Thanks,

```
...
02:03:48.202 INFO  - Sensor Groovy CoberturaSensor
02:03:48.202 INFO  - Analyzing Cobertura report: target/test-reports/cobertura/coverage.xml
02:03:48.402 WARN  - File not found: Route1.groovy
02:03:48.402 WARN  - File not found: Route2.groovy
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

Comment: Can you check sonar-cobertura plugin version and the version of cobertura it supports